# How to pass a output from PHP to Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

I am new to PHP and javascript. Basically I want to pass output from PHP to Javascript.

I have a readStatus.php file:

```
<?php
$myLocalFile = "LEDstate.txt";
$f = fopen($myLocalFile, 'rb');
$theData = fread($f, filesize($myLocalFile));
fclose($f);
if($theData == "1")
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'>"; //image 1
}
else
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_off.png'>"; //image 2
}
?>
```

and I want to place the 2  at the same place in my HTML page by different conditions.

At the HTML page, I have

```
<td><script type="text/javascript" src="readStatus.php"></td>
```

This is not working. Apparently I did something wrong but I couldnt figure it out. Need help here, thanks in advance.

Comment: i think what your trying to do is to use an `include 'readStatus.php'` ?

Comment: Why javascript? You do not need  javascript for this, nor should you use javascript for this. Use pure PHP. Put the content of readStatus.php between the `<td>...</td>` and you are all set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use javascript.

Change your main file to from a html to a php-page and do like this:

```
<?php
$myLocalFile = "LEDstate.txt";
$f = fopen($myLocalFile, 'rb');
$theData = fread($f, filesize($myLocalFile));
fclose($f);
if($theData == "1")
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'>"; //image 1
}
else
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_off.png'>"; //image 2
}
?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try printing your php output in hidden form fields and then use JS to read from these fields and get the data...

Answer (score 0):

What is the data you are actually trying to pass to javascript?

the easiest way to do this would be to write javascript with php in your page:

```
<?php
$myLocalFile = "LEDstate.txt";
$f = fopen($myLocalFile, 'rb');
$theData = fread($f, filesize($myLocalFile));
fclose($f);
if($theData == "1")
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'>"; //image 1
}
else
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_off.png'>"; //image 2
}
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

jsVar = <?php echo $phpVar; ?>;

</script>
```

Comment: The data that I want to pass from js to php is the "echo part", i want to append the corresponding html code by conditions.

Comment: Well then either assign that data to a php variable in your if statement or assign that javascript variable within the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $myLocalFile = "LEDstate.txt"; 
    $f = fopen($myLocalFile, 'rb'); 
    $theData = fread($f, filesize($myLocalFile)); 
    fclose($f); 
    if($theData == "1") 
    { 
        echo "document.write(\"<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'>\");"; //image 1 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        echo "document.write(\"<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_off.png'>\");"; //image 2 
    } 

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a basic understanding problem. What your browser gets from that code is this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php
$myLocalFile = "LEDstate.txt";
$f = fopen($myLocalFile, 'rb');
$theData = fread($f, filesize($myLocalFile));
fclose($f);
if($theData == "1")
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'>"; //image 1
}
else
{
    echo "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_off.png'>"; //image 2
}
?>
</script>
```

That isn't javascript right? you are trying to get the browser to parse PHP code as Javascript, and that isn't possible.

What you should do is use include('readStatus.php') inside the  or simply paste the php code inside the td.

With any of the two solutions you have to change the extension of the HTML to PHP to make it understand the PHP code, otherwise it will parse it as text

Comment: If it worked for one, then the server is configured to process PHP, and thus, the `<script>` tag won't contain PHP, but more HTML, like this: `<script type="text/javascript"><img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'></script>`

Comment: That would happen if the extension of the file is .php, but if it's html (as I imply when he says "html page") it won't understand the php.

Comment: Well the question does say that the filename is `readStatus.php`.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
// do whatever you like
if($theData == "1") {
    $image = "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_on.png'>"; //image 1
} else {
    $image = "<img border='0' src='/cmos/images/device_off.png'>"; //image 2
}
?>
```

And then in html you call like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php include('readStatus.php'); echo $image; ?>">
```